# Entering data into input <Selenium | Watir Ruby>

Tags: methods, undefined, watir

I would like to enter text in the search engine field of the website. I can select input correctly. However, an error occurs when trying to use:

***undefined method `set 'for # Watir :: Input: 0x000055c93c73b850> ***

Code:

````
      sleep 1
      advencedSearch = @ browser.div (: class => "search")
      advencedSearch.a.click ()
      sleep 1
      productSearch = @ browser.div (: class => "filter")
      productSearch.input.click ()
      productSearch.input (: placeholder => "Name or code").set('hi')```
````

Answer (score 2):

The `Watir::Input` is a generic class for all `input` elements. Typically (always?) you want to work with the type specific classes - eg `Watir::TextField`. These specific classes are where methods like `#set` will be available.

Try using `#text_field` instead of `#input`:

```
productSearch.text_field(: placeholder => "Name or code").set('hi')
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it resolved the problem. There is a hollow tic in the top left of this answer you have to click it. Result of your click, it will turn into green.